# Using an array in a MySql WHERE clause in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

I want to take the `conversation_id` values from the following arrays and store them into another array so I can use it in a `WHERE` clause. Is that possible?

```
`Array ( [conversation] => Array ( 
[0] => Array ( 
[conversation_id] => 4
[conversation_subject] => This is just a test 
[conversation_last_reply] => 2016-01-03 20:12:14 
[conversation_unread] => 1 ) 
[1] => Array (
[conversation_id] => 3 
[conversation_subject] => Interview scheduled for monday [conversation_last_reply] => 2016-01-03 18:51:33 
[conversation_unread] => 1 ) 
[2] => Array ( 
[conversation_id] => 2 
[conversation_subject] => Google hangout
[conversation_last_reply] => 2016 [conversation_unread] => 1 )
[3] => Array ( 
[conversation_id] => 1 
[conversation_subject] => testing 
[conversation_last_reply] => 2016
[conversation_unread] => 1 ) ) )`
```

My frame work is codeignitor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can defined a new array and populate that with the `conversation_id` and 
you will be using `$this->db->where_in()` to get the result.

```
$where = [];
foreach($array['conversation'] as $row){
   $where[] = $row['conversation_id'];
}
```

// Model code

```
$this->db->where_in('conversation_id', $where);
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you familiarize yourself with PHP's built-in [`foreach()`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) function.

Comment: i know how to do a for each loop. but how do i do the where clause please? am i going to implode it? i tried . never worked

Comment: Are you using the SELECT `*` in your query?

Comment: no sir. i am selecting fields in about 3 tables i have joined so . and i want the where clause to run for each of the conversation id value.

Comment: Either way, you're going to need to loop through the array and gather all the **`conversation_id`**'s from that array and then use them accordingly.

Comment: if php is your passion, then come on give me an example pleaseeeee